# Creating large adjacency matrix from image in python

Tags: python, image, graph

I would like to create a large, weighted adjacency matrix from an image (so lots of vertices... in the order of > 10^5 vertices) in python. Weights between adjacent pixels are color gradients (I take care of this). Doing it by iterating through pixels is very slow... it takes over 4 minutes. :-( Are there any libraries that can do this nicely in reasonable time?

The following is my code which runs very slowly:

```
def indToCoord(ind, w, h):
    x = ind % w
    y = (ind - x)/h
    return (x,y)

def isAdj(p1, p2, im):
    adj = []
    w, h = im.size
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    if (x1, y1) == (x2, y2):
        return 0
    elif abs(x1 - x2) > 1:
        return 0
    elif abs(y1 - y2) > 1:
        return 0
    elif abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2) >= 2:
        return 0

    return util.colorGradient(im, p1, p2)

def adjForPixel(pixels, p1, im):
    return [isAdj(p1,p2,im) for p2 in pixels]

# The following is the function I use to create an Adjacency Matrix from an image
def getAdjMatrix(im):
    width, height = im.size 
    pixels = [(x,y) for x in xrange(width) for y in xrange(height)]

    pixelAdjMatr = [adjForPixel(pixels, p, im) for p in pixels]
    return pixelAdjMatr

adj_matrix = getAdjMatrix(im)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your current code (iteration) along with a sample of your output

Comment: A pixel can have 2, 3, or 4 adjacent pixels and each pixel has a color gradient value for each of its *neighbors*?  Is the color gradient value for ```p1,p2``` different than ```p2,p1```?

Comment: That's right, they can have 2, 3, or 4 adjacent pixels. The color gradient value for p1, p2 is not different than p2, p1, although computing color gradient is not so computationally expensive.

Comment: Your implementation is very inefficient. When you do "[isAdj(p1,p2,im) for p2 in pixels]", you are iterating over every pixel in the image and checking if it's adjacent to p1. But you don't need to do this - there are at most 4 pixels that are adjacent to p1, and you can easily create the list of them directly. I would guess that if you did that, your routine would run in a reasonable time without needing to use an external library.

Answer (score 1):

[img_to_graph](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.img_to_graph.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.img_to_graph) will do the trick. This creates a so-called "connectivity matrix". The adjacency matrix is such a ubiquitous and important term that `sklearn`'s departure here is not awesome.

But this function will do the trick.  I found that `networkx`'s function, cited above, was only useful for graphs. In order to convert an image to a `networkx` graph from a `numpy` array, you are pretty much reduced to interpreted for loop writing.  This is because the `networkx` library does provide an optimized `numpy->graph` function, but that function assumes the `numpy` array is **already an adjacency matrix**.

This is a compiled `-O3 --simd --omp` only loop scenario for any reasonably sized images, and may even benefit from some cache optimization strategies (ruling out python3's `numba` Just-In-Time compiler).

That makes the `networkx` answer another problem. I'd go ahead and use the `sklearn` function there:

```
sklearn.feature_extraction.image.img_to_graph(your_img)  
# returns scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Python module/library NetworkX has an adjacency matrix implementation.  It returns a scipy matrix

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html

```
import networkx as nx
import scipy as sp
g = nx.Graph([(1,1)])
a = nx.adjacency_matrix(g)
print a, type(a)
```

returns

```
(0, 0)  1 <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck!